# Implementing Stripe backend - best practice to store data locally or rely on API Calls?

Tags: rest, stripe-payments

Totally new to server-side programming and I am wondering about best practices regarding gathering information from a service like Stripe Payments, for example.

For some context -- a stripe customer can have multiple payment cards, one of which is considered the default payment card.

Now lets say a client hits my server and wants the default payment card for customer XX. My question is: should I be maintaining my own stripe database info, or should I just forward that request to stripe directly?

On the one hand, storing that information locally means I don't have to rely on a second network request to gather that information -- I can just send back directly what is in my database.

On the other hand, storing that information locally means I've got more code to maintain, and now I've got to worry about keeping it reflective of the true data over at stripe. That problem is solvable, but does the cost of doing so outweigh the negatives of extra API calls??

Any thoughts? I'd love to hear some opinions as this is very new to me :)

thanks!

Comment: As a general rule try keeping as much as possible on Stripe, otherwise you will have data anomaly and it'll become impossible to fix your local data. Basically severe sync issues. some more info here. https://supremecodr.com/quick-point-on-avoiding-data-anomalies/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally it's a good idea to keep a local copy of the data you get from Stripe API in your own database. Otherwise you will have to make too many calls to Stripe API which will slow down your server requests.
In order to keep your local database synchronized with Stripe you should use the webhooks in Stripe.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: It'd be neat to expand this answer to mention possible security implications of storing Stripe data locally. Obviously, I mean data other than super sensitive things like credit card numbers - but e.g. charge ids, card decline reasons, etc.

Comment: This seems like an opinionated answer. It could be argued that doing so would mean you're duplicating data and have to keep the two in sync.

Comment: On the other hand, I would argue that there is risk on relying on a third-party to store your data. What would happen if Stripe servers go down? Or if API changes occur? Although, perhaps you could solve this by keeping a local backup.